# Writing hundreds of data objects to a Mongo database

Tags: java, multithreading, mongodb, morphia

I am working on a Minecraft network which has several servers manipulating 'user-objects', which is just a Mongo document. After a user object is modified it need to be written to the database immediately, otherwise it may be overwritten in other servers (which have an older version of the user object), but sometimes hundreds of objects need to be written away in a short amount of time.. (in a few seconds). My question is: How can I easily write objects to a MongoDB database without really overload the database..

I have been thinking up an idea but I have no idea if it is relevant:
- Create some sort of queue in another thread, everytime an data object gets need to be saved into the database it gets in the queue and then in the 'queue thread' the objects will be saved one by one with some sort of interval..

Thanks in advance

btw Im using Morphia as framework in Java

Answer (score 2):

"hundreds of objects [...] in a few seconds" doesn't sound that much. How much can you do at the moment?

The setting most important for the speed of write operations is the [WriteConcern](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/WriteConcern.html). What are you using at the moment and is this the right setting for your project (data safety vs speed)?

If you need to do many write operations at once, you can probably speed up things with bulk operations. They have been added in MongoDB 2.6 and Morphia supports them as well — see this [unit test](https://github.com/mongodb/morphia/blob/76aa6ce28bcf63bfa8c1d1fe6f50fab71c259e8a/morphia/src/test/java/org/mongodb/morphia/TestDatastore.java#L473).

I would be very cautious with a queue:

- Do you really need it? Depending on your hardware and configuration you should be able to do hundreds or even thousands of write operations per second.
- Is async really the best approach for you? The producer of the write operation / message can only assume his change has been applied, but it probably has not and is still waiting in the queue to be written. Is this the intended behaviour?
- Does it make your life easier? You need to know another piece of software, which adds many new and most likely unforeseen problems.
- If you need to scale your writes, why not use sharding? No additional technology and your code will behave the same with and without it.

You might want to read the following blogpost on why you probably want to avoid queues for this kind of operation in general: http://widgetsandshit.com/teddziuba/2011/02/the-case-against-queues.html